# What does the following requirement mean?

Tags: unit-test

I have been given following requirement,

1. Test class with no assert.
2. Test method with no assert.

The first one is for a test class and the second one is for the apex class.

What does these mean?

Answer (score 4):

The requirement makes it sound like the customer only wants test code that generates sufficient code coverage for deployment, and not code that actually verifies your scripts are doing what they're supposed to.

I cannot think of any scenario where it would be proper to not use assert statements in test code - they verify that your code is working as it should in the target environment as it changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have to use assert in the code.
Refer the following example :

```
@isTest
class TestLeadZipZone {
  static testMethod void test() {
    zip_code__c z = new zip_code__c(name='12345', zone__c='Zone 1');
      insert z;
     // system.assertEquals('Zone 1',z.Zone__c);
     // system.assertEquals('12345',z.name);
  }
}
```